# How to multiply respective objects of NSArray and get the sum?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have one array with data A=[a,b,c] and another with data B=[d,e,f]. I need to perform this type of operation a.d+ b.e+c.f (Note=Here (.) denotes multplication)and get the result. How can i do that using Objective-C?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? That is a very basic task, a simple for-loop should do.

Comment: Isn't this just a vector multiplication?

Comment: @luk2302 I have tried below

` NSArray *a = @[@(1),@(2)];
    NSArray *b = @[@(3),@(4)];
    
    NSArray *c=[a arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:b];
    
    NSNumber * ssum = [c valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
    
    NSLog(@"sum %@",ssum); 
`

Comment: @floyddd Don't post code in the comments. Update your question with all relevant code and details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSNumber *myNum1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    NSNumber *myNum2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    NSNumber *myNum3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];

    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myNum1, myNum2, myNum3, nil];
    NSArray *b = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myNum1, myNum2, myNum3, nil];
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<[a count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", (NSNumber*)[a objectAtIndex:i]);
        sum =sum +[(NSNumber*)[a objectAtIndex:i] intValue]*[(NSNumber*)[b objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    }
    NSLog(@"Sum is %d", sum);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Better assert that the two arrays have the same length; otherwise you will get a range exception.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function that does the multiplication and addition like this:

```
- (double)multiply:(NSArray <NSNumber *> *)vector1 withVector:(NSArray <NSNumber *> *)vector2 {
    NSAssert(vector1.count == vector2.count, @"Both arrays should contain the same number of elements");

    __block double result = 0;
    [vector1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        double first = obj.doubleValue;
        double second = vector2[idx].doubleValue;
        result += first * second;
    }];

    return result;
}
```

This uses a block enumeration method on NSArray which gives me in index and a value, which I can use to get the value at the same index in the second array. Note also that I am using a typed array, so I don't have to cast the values to NSNumbers when using them.

Now you can just use the function:

```
NSArray *a = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSArray *b = @[@4, @5, @6];
NSArray *c = @[@1, @1, @1];

double res1 = [self multiply:a withVector:b]; // => 32.000000 
double res2 = [self multiply:b withVector:c]; // => 15.000000
double res3 = [self multiply:c withVector:a]; // => 6.000000
```